# C# MVVM: MenuItem Command don´t execute in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I created a Delete MenuItem and binding a command to it. 
Now I have the problem, if I am pressing the Delete MenuItem, nothing happens. Also if the program is executed with the debugger, it never reaches the private void DeleteItem.

**xaml:**

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Background="#F5F5F5" Width="80" Height="60" Margin="0,5,5,5">
                    <Border.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Delete"
                                      Command="{Binding Path=DeleteItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType= MenuItem}}">
                                <MenuItem.Icon>
                                    <Label FontFamily="#FontAwesome" Content="&#xf1f8;" />
                                </MenuItem.Icon>
                            </MenuItem>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Border.ContextMenu>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public ICommand DeleteItemCommand { get; set; } 
DeleteItemCommand = new RelayCommand(DeleteItem);

private void DeleteItem(object obj)
{
    try
    {
        // Do Magic
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(error);
    }
}
```

Would be great, if someone could help me or have any ideas how to solve it, because i can´t find the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ContextMenu is indeed not part of the visual tree. But I think because of that reason RelativeSource will not work because the binding will look up to the visual tree for the datacontext. contextMenu is not part of that visual tree so it will not find the proper datacontext. I've found a solution for this in the past using a proxy element in the resources for the window. Then set this proxyelement as content for a hidden contentcontrol in the window. On the menuItem set the CommandBinding to Datacontext.DeleteCommand and the soure to the static resource proxyelement. It is a bit hackish, but it works.
So to show some xaml, try this:
First in the resources of the window create a frameworkelement with the datacontext set to the windows datacontext (the viewmodel)

```
<Window.Resources>
        <FrameworkElement x:Key="ProxyElement" DataContext="{Binding}"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then use the resource for the content of a collapsed content control. And set the proper binding to the menuItem. Something like this:

```
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ContentControl Visibility="Collapsed" Content="{StaticResource ProxyElement}"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="lbTest" Grid.Row="1">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Background="#F5F5F5" Width="80" Height="60" Margin="0,5,5,5">
                        <Border.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="Delete"
                                          Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand, Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}}">
                                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                                        <Label FontFamily="#FontAwesome" Content="&#xf1f8;" />
                                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                                </MenuItem>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </Border.ContextMenu>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

This should work. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but try using Binding instead of Binding Path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I already tried it, sadly it didn´t work

Answer (score 0):

ContextMenu is not part of VisualTree, that's why the binding fails. You can use some kind of relay like **ContextMenu.PlacementTarget.Tag.Property** as a cache for the second trail of binding search.

```
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Command="my:ImgTreeView.Folders" Header="Folders"
                          IsEnabled="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.IsCheckFolder, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="StarFolders.png" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <!-- ... -->
        </ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Thank you. I am little bit confused by the VisualTree. Does it also contain ListBox or just the TreeView? Greets Blackbear

Comment: ContextMenu is from the BAse library of popup framework element, Actually, the popup is a WPF Primitives Control. Primitives would not be included in the Visual Tree.